# Python Tkinter - How to make a child frame with image inside a set width

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm working on a program, which I'm building using python's tkinter gui library.

## My 2 Problems

1. I'm trying to make a frame which will house a screenshot of the selected website. I have the frame and image created, but the frame is not anchoring to the right side of the window as expected. When the label element inside the frame has an image the frame is the expected length
   [image: with screenshot]
   But, **when the selected site does not have an image yet the frame is not stretching all the way to the right side of the window.**
   [image: without screenshot]
   Below is the portion of my code where I set up the image container/frame and respective image.

   ```
   self.frame_ImageContainer = Frame(self.tab_Details, width=320, height=180, bg='black', bd=2)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid(column=4, row=0, rowspan=11, columnspan=3, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
   self.button_TakeScreenshot = Button(self.frame_ImageContainer, text='Take Screenshot', command=self.fn_RunScraper)
   self.button_TakeScreenshot.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=(E, W))
   self.widget_Image = Label(self.frame_ImageContainer, compound='top')
   self.widget_Image.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=12, columnspan=3, sticky=N)

   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(6, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(8, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(9, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(10, weight=1)
   self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_rowconfigure(11, weight=1)
   ```
2. **The Take Screenshot button will not center both vertically & horizontally**. I've attempted to center the Take Screenshot button in the middle of the frame, but it only applies vertically currently. I've also tried using `.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor=CENTER)`, but when I try that the frame/image doesn't even show up on the screen.

## What I'm trying to accomplish

1. Making the image frame a set width
2. Showing a Take Screenshot button in the center of the image frame when a site does not have a screenshot yet.

## In Question Form

1. How can I make the frame & image stay a consistent width & height (320x180)?
2. How can I center the Take Screenshot button both vertically and horizontally inside the Image frame?

Comment: Any particular reason for the lack of [mcve]?

Comment: @Nae How is this *not* a complete & minimal example? I give the snippet of code where I'm creating the the elements along with the current behavior & expected behavior. Would you prefer that I post the entire 229-line file?

Comment: [mcve] is _neither_ of those. If you've given the guide a read you'd know.

Comment: Thanks for being of no help. Have an nice day :)

Comment: @Nae is right: this is not a [mcve] because it's not **C**omplete. We can't run the code in order to duplicate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want a frame to have a fixed size then simply unset its propagation for the layout manager its children use, to discard the size change based on its children's size demands, while defining setting its `width` and `height`:

```
frame = tk.Frame(..., width=320, height=180, ...)
#frame.grid_propagate(False) # uncomment if children use pack
frame.pack_propagate(False) # uncomment if children use grid
```

2. For centering a widget one easy way is using `place`:

```
widget.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')
```

[A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that accomplishes both:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = tk.Frame(root, width=320, height=180, bg='#f48024')
    img = Image.new('RGB', (640, 360), color=(0, 121, 152))
    frame.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    frame_s_label = tk.Label(frame, image=frame.image)
    button = tk.Button(frame, text="Button")
    button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')

    frame.grid()
    #frame.grid_propagate(False) # uncomment if children use pack
    frame.pack_propagate(False) # uncomment if children use grid
    frame_s_label.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: `.grid_propagate(False)` & `.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the frame & image stay a consistent width & height (320x180)?

If you want the frame to be a specific size, start by giving it a specific size. Next, either use `place` to add widgets to it, or turn geometry propagation off if using `grid` or `pack`

```
# if using pack:
self.frame_ImageContainer.pack_propagate(False)

# if using grid:
self.frame_ImageContainer.grid_propagate(False)
```

> How can I center the Take Screenshot button both vertically and horizontally inside the Image frame?

The easiest way is to use `place`, since it won't affect the size of its master, and you can provide relative coordinates.

```
self.button_TakeScreenshot.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")
```